# cypress-fail-fast not skipping tests after a failed test

Tags: cypress

I'm using the `cypress-fail-fast` plugin > https://github.com/javierbrea/cypress-fail-fast in my Typescript Cypress config, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
// cypress.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from 'cypress';
import plugin from './cypress/plugins/index';

export default defineConfig({
    projectId: '**',
    fixturesFolder: 'cypress/fixtures',
    screenshotOnRunFailure: true,
    video: true,
    videoCompression: 1,
    viewportHeight: 1000,
    viewportWidth: 1600,
    e2e: {
        env: {
            API_URL: '**',
            CYPRESS_PASSWORD: '**',
        },
        supportFile: 'cypress/support/index.ts',
        baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200',
        experimentalInteractiveRunEvents: true,
        setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
            plugin(on, config);
        },
    },
});
```

```
// supprt/index.ts
import './commands';
import './hooks';
import 'cypress-real-events/support';
import 'cypress-file-upload';
import 'cypress-fail-fast/plugin';
```

That's how I got it set up, but after a test fails in a spec, it still runs each test.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing adding the plugin to your node events for e2e.

Per the docs:

```
// cypress.config.js
module.exports = {
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      require("cypress-fail-fast/plugin")(on, config);
      return config;
    },
    specPattern: "cypress/integration/**/*.js",
  },
};
```

So in your case, that would be:

```js
...
    e2e: {
        env: {
            API_URL: '**',
            CYPRESS_PASSWORD: '**',
        },
        supportFile: 'cypress/support/index.ts',
        baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200',
        experimentalInteractiveRunEvents: true,
        setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
            plugin(on, config);
            require("cypress-fail-fast/plugin")(on, config);
        },
    },
...
```

Comment: I cannot use require in TypeScript.

Answer (score 0):

@agoff was right, but there was another issue, so I'll explain here.

```js
// support/index.ts
...
import 'cypress-fail-fast';
```

I added `/plugin` to the import, which wasn't needed.

And I did have to declare `cypressFailFast` in my `setupNodeEvents`.

I declare the `plugin` function like so:

```js
setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
    plugin(on, config);
},
```

`plugin` here refers to: `import plugin from './cypress/plugins/index';`

And in that file I declare:

```js
export default function plugin(on, config) {
    cypressFailFast(on, config);
    ...
```

Now everything works as expected:

[image]